# $request->only() return empty array in laravel 7.9

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-7

I have a mess while laravel 5.4 to 7.9, I have read the follow document: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests , but I am not clear in my case:

[image]

In laravel 5.4, it returns an array:

[image: laravel 5.4]

It's an emty array in laravel 7.9:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are describing is expected behaviour and was changed in between versions.

#### Documentation from Laravel 5.4 [Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-input)

The `only` method returns all of the key / value pairs that you request, even if the key is not present on the incoming request. When the key is not present on the request, the value will be `null`.

#### Documentation from Laravel 7.9 [Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#retrieving-input)

The `only` method returns all of the key / value pairs that you request; however, it will not return key / value pairs that are not present on the request.